# C++ duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64..incrementing an enum type

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to increment an enum type so I overloaded the operator ++ this way:

```
 enum QuarterType{
            FIRST_QUARTER,
            SECOND_QUARTER,
            THIRD_QUARTER,
            FOURTH_QUARTER
        };
```

overloading Operator++:

```
QuarterType& operator++(QuarterType& quarter){
    switch (quarter) {
        case FIRST_QUARTER:
            return quarter= SECOND_QUARTER;
        case SECOND_QUARTER:
            return quarter=THIRD_QUARTER;
        case THIRD_QUARTER:
            return quarter=FOURTH_QUARTER;
        case FOURTH_QUARTER:
            return quarter=FIRST_QUARTER;
    }
}
```

but when I compile the project I get the error:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN3mtmppERNS_11QuarterTypeE in:
    /Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtm-crtygivbbxwmodgeasndvnjnpczt/Build/Intermediates/mtm.build/Debug/mtm.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SecurityExample.o
    /Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtm-crtygivbbxwmodgeasndvnjnpczt/Build/Intermediates/mtm.build/Debug/mtm.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Quarters.o
duplicate symbol __ZN3mtmppERNS_11QuarterTypeE in:
    /Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtm-crtygivbbxwmodgeasndvnjnpczt/Build/Intermediates/mtm.build/Debug/mtm.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SecurityExample.o
    /Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtm-crtygivbbxwmodgeasndvnjnpczt/Build/Intermediates/mtm.build/Debug/mtm.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Security.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

how can I fix that? and what's the right way or a better way to increment an enum type?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/). Guessing that you forgot to guard the header or something. Please post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does the error remain if you declare operator++ as inline? Also, for implementation you could use enum class and modulo arithmetic.

Comment: @SergeRogatch declaring the operator as inline solved the problem, but I don't get it! Can you explain it please? 
Thanks :)

Comment: @Raw305, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that your operator++ gets exported from multiple compilation units. That could lead to a duplicate symbol error and the cause for that could be definition (not just declaration) of operator++ in a header file. The following options can be used to solve the problem:

1. Keep operator++ in a header file, but declare it as `inline`
2. Leave only the declaration in the header file and move the definition into a .cpp file

Answering the second question (about a better way to increment enum type), I think it is the following in C++11 ( -std=c++11 option to clang compiler):

```
enum class QuarterType : int {
    FIRST_QUARTER = 0,
    SECOND_QUARTER = 1,
    THIRD_QUARTER = 2,
    FOURTH_QUARTER = 3,
    TOTAL_QUARTERS = 4
};
inline QuarterType& operator++(QuarterType& quarter) {
    int currentQuarter = static_cast<int>(quarter);
    int nextQuarter = (currentQuarter+1)
        % static_cast<int>(QuarterType::TOTAL_QUARTERS);
    quarter = static_cast<QuarterType>(nextQuarter);
    return quarter;
}
```

Comment: I tried using the way you suggested and I've got a "constness" issue and a warning saying "returning reference to local temporary object".. you might want to take a look at the way I fixed it, (I posted an answer)

Comment: @Raw305, indeed, I made a mistake. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You were right, It didn't work properly (the way I fixed it).. but yours did.. I'm a beginner actually so I keep missing simple details :(
Thanks a lot :)